# How to continue the async look even after an exception?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

In my `Node.js` application I have array called `employees` which store the list of emails. I parse that list and try to send email for each person individually by [nodemailer](https://nodemailer.com/about/) package. Also I use [for-async](https://github.com/jwchang0206/forAsync) package.

An error may occur in one of the iterations of the loop. I want to continue the loop even if an error occurs. It seems like I can't use `continue` statement in my case What solutions do you recommend?

```
const forAsync = require('for-async');

forAsync(employees, (employee) => {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        // Set options.
        const options = {
            from: process.env.EMAIL,
            to: employee,
            subject: "System notification",
            html: html
        };

        // Send mail with defined transport object.
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            setTimeout(() => {
                transporter.sendMail(options, (error) => {
                    if(error) {
                        console.log(error);
                        reject(error);
                    } else {
                        resolve();
                    }
                });
            }, 1000);
        }).then(() => {
            resolve();
        }).catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
        );
    });
});
```

**EDIT:**

```
router.post('/notifications', function(request, response) {
    // Make sql requests to the database.

    Promise.all([firstQuery, secondQuery, thirdQuery]).then(responses => {
        // Some logic

        await Promise.all(employees.map(async (employee) => { // <- PROBLEM
            try {
                await sendEmail(transporter, options);
            } catch (error) {
                // Error sending this specific email, just report it and ignore
                console.log(error);
            }
        }));
    });
});
```

Comment: What's `forAsync`?

Comment: Why the one second delay?

Comment: Fundamentally, if you want the loop (which presumably is implemented in `forAsync`) to continue, make sure you catch errors/rejections during the loop body. But it looks to me like you do that, because the inner promise may reject, but the outer promise catches that rejection and turns it into a fulfillment with `undefined` via the `.catch` at the end...

Comment: I use the [for-async](https://www.npmjs.com/package/forAsync) package. It is probably already outdated, but it works without problems. Anyway, I'm thinking of replacing it with something else. I will be grateful for your advice.

Comment: Sadly, that package documentation doesn't tell you what it's *for*. :-) Anyway, I think if you're using any vaguely-modern version of Node.js, I'd use an `async` function and a `for` loop with an `await` inside it (if you want to do these things one ta a time). :-)

Comment: My Node.js version is `10.15.0`. Well, that package is for async loop functions. The main task, I need to asynchronously send emails in a loop.

Comment: You're in good shape, Node 10 has full support for `async` functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're using a fairly recent version of Node.js, I'd use an `async` function for this and a `for` loop.

First, since `transporter.sendEmail` is an old callback-style function, I'd create a wrapper for it in some utilities module:

```
function sendEmail(transporter, options) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        transporter.sendMail(options, (error) => {
            if (error) {
                reject(error);
            } else {
                resolve();
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Then the loop (in an `async` function) would be:

```
for (const employee of employees) {
    try {
        await sendEmail(transporter, {
            from: process.env.EMAIL,
            to: employee,
            subject: "System notification",
            html: html
        });
    } catch (error) {
        // Error sending this specific email, just report it and ignore
        console.log(error);
    }
}
```

The `try`/`catch` prevents any errors or promise rejections from propagating out of the loop, so the loop continues. Note that the emails will be sent in *series*, not in *parallel*.

I've removed the one-second delay on the assumption you didn't really need it, but if you want it, add a `delay` function to your utilities:

```
function delay(ms, value) {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms, value));
}
```

Then insert this in the `for` loop:

```
await delay(1000);
```

---

If you wanted to do this in parallel instead of in series, you'd want `Promise.all` and a rejection handler for the individual promises:

```
await Promise.all(employees.map(async (employee) => {
    try {
        await sendEmail(transporter, {
            from: process.env.EMAIL,
            to: employee,
            subject: "System notification",
            html: html
        });
    } catch (error) {
        // Error sending this specific email, just report it and ignore
        console.log(error);
    }
}));
```

or

```
await Promise.all(employees.map(employee => sendEmail(transporter, {
        from: process.env.EMAIL,
        to: employee,
        subject: "System notification",
        html: html
    }).catch(error) {
        // Error sending this specific email, just report it and ignore
        console.log(error);
    })
);
```

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. I tried to use the last option of your post. I can't use `await` statement before `Promise.all`. I see such error: `SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function`. Do you have any ideas? Can you check my post again, please?! I add my current code.

Comment: @NurzhanNogerbek - I'd use an `async` function, that's what that example and the others are meant to be in. If you don't want to use an `async` function, remove `await` and use fulfillment and rejection handlers (`.then`, `.catch`, ...).